# Parse string with lex in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm following [Gentle introduction to Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/stdclasses.html) tutorial and the code presented there seems to be broken. I need to understand whether it is so, or my seeing of the concept is wrong.

I am implementing parser for custom type:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

printing function for convenience

```
showsTree              :: Show a => Tree a -> String -> String
showsTree (Leaf x)     = shows x
showsTree (Branch l r) = ('<':) . showsTree l . ('|':) . showsTree r . ('>':)

instance Show a => Show (Tree a) where 
    showsPrec _ x = showsTree x
```

this parser is fine but breaks when *there are* spaces

```
readsTree         :: (Read a) => String -> [(Tree a, String)]
readsTree ('<':s) =  [(Branch l r, u) | (l, '|':t) <- readsTree s,
                                        (r, '>':u) <- readsTree t ]
readsTree s       =  [(Leaf x, t)     | (x,t)      <- reads s]
```

this one is said to be a better solution, but it does not work *without* spaces

```
readsTree_lex    :: (Read a) => String -> [(Tree a, String)]
readsTree_lex s  = [(Branch l r, x) | ("<", t) <- lex s,
                                   (l, u)   <- readsTree_lex t,
                                   ("|", v) <- lex u,
                                   (r, w)   <- readsTree_lex v,
                                   (">", x) <- lex w ]
                ++
                [(Leaf x, t)     | (x, t)   <- reads s ]
```

next I pick one of parsers to use with `read`

```
instance Read a => Read (Tree a) where
    readsPrec _ s = readsTree s
```

then I load it in ghci using Leksah debug mode (this is unrelevant, I guess), and try to parse two strings:

```
    read "<1|<2|3>>"   :: Tree Int -- succeeds with readsTree
    read "<1| <2|3> >" :: Tree Int -- succeeds with readsTree_lex
```

when `lex` encounters `|<2...` part of the former string, it splits onto `("|<", _)`. That does not match `("|", v) <- lex u` part of parser and fails to complete parsing.

There are two questions arising:

1. how do I define parser that really *ignores* spaces, not *requires* them?
2. how can I define rules for splitting encountered literals with lex

speaking of second question -- it is asked more of curiousity as defining my own lexer seems to be more correct than defining rules of existing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lex` splits into *Haskell* lexemes, skipping whitespace.

This means that since Haskell permits `|<` as a lexeme, `lex` will not split it into two lexemes, since that's not how it parses in Haskell.

You can only use `lex` in your parser if you're using the same (or similar) syntactic rules to Haskell.

If you want to *ignore* all whitespace (as opposed to making any whitespace equivalent to one space), it's much simpler and more efficient to first run `filter (not.isSpace)`.

Comment: that was something I was unsure of. I still don't understand why this is an example in the book. Maybe lex implementation changed for the past decade.

Comment: It does say it follows Haskell lexical rules, perhaps they were assuming you wouldn't give it `"<3|<4,5>>"` on the grounds that Haskell would require a space between `|` and `<` to distinguish from a potential `|<` operator. Thius should be made very explicit in the text, though, I agree.

Comment: I found an answer to this (seemingly) inside codebase for this book. That codebase was not included with my (translated) version, which led me to not noticing that earlier. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: using `filter` seems to be best solution, because either of my variants fails to remove junk from input.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this seems to be a small gap between text of [Gentle introduction to Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/stdclasses.html) and its [code samples](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/code/part16.lhs), plus an error in sample code.

there should also be one more lexer, but there is no working example (satisfying my need) in codebase, so I written one. Please point out any flaw in it:

```
lexAll :: ReadS String
lexAll s = case lex s of
            [("",_)] -> []                                  -- nothing to parse.
            [(c, r)] -> if length c == 1 then [(c, r)]      -- we will try to match
                           else [(c, r), ([head s], tail s)]-- not only as it was 
            any_else -> any_else                            -- parsed but also splitted
```

author sais:

> Finally, the complete reader.  This is not sensitive to white space as
>   were the previous versions.  When you derive the Show class for a data
>   type the reader generated automatically is similar to this in style.

but `lexAll` should be used instead of lex (which seems to be said error):

```
readsTree' :: (Read a) => ReadS (Tree a)
readsTree' s = [(Branch l r, x) | ("<", t) <- lexAll s,
                  (l, u)   <- readsTree' t,
                                  ("|", v) <- lexAll u,
                                  (r, w)   <- readsTree' v,
                  (">", x) <- lexAll w ]
                ++
                [(Leaf x, t)    | (x, t) <- reads s]
```